# Unable to launch distribution package on Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant

I am compiling my java project in eclipse through ANT builder.
I am able to produce distribution package(.zip) without errors and I want to launch this in Apache Tomcat 7 server
The problem is when I start the server http://localhost:8080/cw-safeperimeter-3.1.7.423.

```
Then , it is showing ERROR 404   
Type Status report

message /cw-safeperimeter-3.1.7.423/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

While Launching Server, I am not seeing any exception in Eclipse Console.
I am using Eclipse Mars
Note: I am able to launch Tomcat Server with URL: http://localhost:8080
Any Help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Why are you packaging in .zip instead of .jar?

Comment: I just tried that .....Even if i make .jar file then also it is showing the same HTTP 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not forget to add the application to your server before you launch it.

Comment: Yes, I am pasting it in webapps folder of tomcat server

Comment: Please provide more details about your application: ANT script, web.xml, etc.